# next js route groups issue

Tags: next.js, runtime-error, router, next.js13

when i am calling http://localhost:3000/dashboard its working fine because its in app directory , but when i am calling http://localhost:3000/connections it shows the error Error: The default export is not a React Component in page: "/connections" and when i move connections component to app directory it works fine .

[This is my folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oRcnP.png)

the issue is related to route groups .

This is the code of app > (main) > (pages) > connections > page.tsx
[This is the code of app > (main) > (pages) > connections > page.tsx](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HiXg5.png)

i did try restarting the server  changing the name of component but it doesnt work , the structure looks like it should work fine but dont know what is creating an issue

Comment: I think there is some problem in layout.tsx files inside `(main)`